# Linking UIActionSheet buttons with a current IBAction

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have got created a UIActionsheet programatically however I can't figure out how to link it to an existing IBAction.

```
    -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    self.label.text = @"Destructive Button Clicked";
          }}
```

This is my code where i click on a button and I want it to link to the following IBAction that i have already got.

```
    - (IBAction)doButton;
```

So, how would i go about linking this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If I answered your question, please be sure to "Accept my answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
self.label.text = @"Destructive Button Clicked";
[self doButton];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to add a UIActionSheetDelegate to your class and call the action sheet in your IBAction.

.h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>

-(IBAction)doButton;

@end
```

.m file

```
-(IBAction)doButton {

UIActionSheet *doSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Button 0", @"Button 1", nil];

[doSheet showInView:self.view];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex {
       if (buttonIndex == 0) {
             //Do Something
       }
       if(buttonIndex == 1) {
            //Do Something else
       }
}
```